# SilverStripe querying all the DataObject table in one go

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am developing a website using the SilverStripe CMS. I am having a little problem with querying DataObjects. I am trying to get all the DataObjects in one go as follows to optimize performance:

```
DataObject::get();
```

When call this I get the following error:

```
[Emergency] Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Call ::get() instead of DataObject::get()
```

If I could query it, I would like to do further operations like this:

```
DataObject::get()->filterAny([ 'ClassName' => 'ClassName' ]);
```

I have also tried to use the following query:

```
$sqlQuery = new SQLQuery();
$sqlQuery->setFrom('Player');
```

But the issue is that I do not know what is the name of the global / parent table name DataObject.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do in SilverStripe and, if so, how?

Comment: try calling with Object name say for Gallery model
$gallery = App\Model\Gallery::get()

Comment: Hi @thomaspaulson, if I have to use the object names, I have to create multiple queries. Is there a way to query all the data objects from the one main table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We cannot call `DataObject::get()` to retrieve all `DataObjects` in one go. `DataObject` itself does not have a database table and therefore cannot be queried.

We cannot fetch all custom data objects in one query.

We can get all *pages* in one query by calling `Sitetree::get()`.

If we want to be able to fetch all our own custom `DataObjects` in one query we would need to start by creating a `BaseObject` and having all our custom `DataObjects` extend `BaseObject`.

**BaseObject**

```
use SilverStripe\ORM\DataObject;

class BaseObject extends DataObject
{
}
```

**Other custom classes**

```
class ExampleObject extends BaseObject
{
}

class AnotherExampleObject extends BaseObject
{
}
```

We can then call `BaseObject::get()` to fetch all our custom objects and call `SiteTree::get()` to get all our pages.

Note, this will still not get any `DataObjects` defined in any installed modules, including the SilverStripe core. This includes `Member`, `File`, `SiteConfig` etc. These will always need to be retrieved with their own `get()` requests.

Comment: Thanks @3dgoo. This is really helpful. Now, I have to redesign my database.